# Python 2.7 : difference between exit() and raise ValueError("example")

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Is there any difference between `exit()` and `raise ValueError("example")` except for the fact that I will have an error print on my output when using `raise ValueError("example")` ?

Comment: `exit` exits, while `raise` raises an error, which indicates there has been an error, and can be caught

Comment: `sys.exit()` raises `SystemExit`, which terminates the interpreter without a traceback, but the principle is the same, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a huge difference.

`sys.exit()` raises a `SystemExit` exception, which Python always catches and turns into a program exit code.

Raising `ValueError`, if uncaught, triggers the [`sys.excepthook()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) handler, after which Python exits. The default except hook prints the traceback of the exception to `stderr`, after which Python exits with an exit code of 1.

The `sys.excepthook()` function is never called for `SystemExit`, so you cannot customize the handling of that exception, but you *can* handle the handling of `ValueError` and other exceptions.